# Pandas column with amount range

Tags: pandas

We have a column like below

```
name  salary-range
 A     $53K-$99K
 B     $41K-$78K
 c     $97K-$129K
 D     $29K-$38K
```

we need to find the name with highest salary

dtype of salary-range is object , is there any easy way to convert the column to int64 and check  for the with highest salary?

Comment: `highest salary range` is maximal difference?

Comment: @jezrael it is the one which has the higest salary which D  $97K-$129K , i will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for get numbers, convert to integers:

```
s = (df.set_index('name')['salary-range']
       .str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]
       .astype(int)
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
print (s)
name
A     53
A     99
B     41
B     78
c     97
c    129
D     29
D     38
Name: 0, dtype: int32
```

Last get names by maximal value by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
a = s.idxmax()
print (a)
c
```

Comment: thank you Series.str.extractall  and Series.unstack: will work for me

Comment: @parikannappan - I change it a bit for maximal number name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
In [972]: df.sort_values('salary-range').tail(1)['name']
Out[972]: 
2    c
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, the kind of data frame OP has, my solution works for that.

Comment: Let's wait for OP to see if he has complex cases.

Comment: Try `$53K-$999K` and it return `c` instead `A`, solution is bad

Comment: @jezrael No. Even then the correct answer would be `c` not `A` because OP wants highest salary, not highest salary range.

Comment: `999` is highest salary ;)